# Does compilation with -g result in slower code?

Tags: optimization, gcc

I am using a package that is compiled using `gcc -O3 -g`.

Since some function calls to that code are the slowest part of my program I am wondering if the `-g` could be the culprit? Or should it not matter in terms of runtime?

Comment: Well, did you try taking out the `-g` flag, and re-measuring the performance?

Comment: @Oli: If the answers had been "no there is no way that can matter since -O3 is turned on" then I wouldn't have bothered to test. But given that the answers are slightly vague I think I'll do the test.

Comment: Okay, indeed didn't make a difference, even though those functions were called 100 million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since -O3 implies aggressive inlining, and -g implies avoiding inlining so that the debugger can have function addresses, those options are somewhat at odds. Nevertheless in general -O3 wins, and aside from a somewhat larger binary -- and the minor speed effects that might come from paging or nonlocality -- it should not make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

`-g` will make your code bigger (added space for debug symbols) and will disable some optimizations like inlining, but probably not appreciably slower.

Answer (score 0):

If your real question is "Why is it slow?"
[there's an easy way to find out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)